# on macOS high sierra /usr/bin/python as arg is being changed to /usr/bin/python27

Tags: python, macos

Can anyone explain this:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv"  /usr/bin/python
['-c', '/usr/bin/python2.7']
```

I'd expect the second arg to be /usr/bin/python

(I have macports installed if that makes any difference)

It seems like the shell itself is changing it before the python script gets ahold of it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Even if they were, it shouldn't have this effect. This isn't `argv[0]` being changed; this is `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: What does `echo /usr/bin/python` display?

Comment: *nod*. Looking at the binary, `/usr/bin/python` is a shim (which inspects the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` environment variable), not a real Python executable. Doing weird unexpected things is what shims do -- if you didn't want to do something odd, there'd be no need for a shim.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the shim, rewriting too much of the command line.

Comment: I agree. Its author at Apple might have been thinking about cases like `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but if they'd thought a little more, they'd realize that by the time the argv gets to them, the `env` is already stripped off.

Comment: $ echo /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python